# ajax json response error 404 on IIS7

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter, iis-7

I'm using datatables on my webpage and it works fine on localhost, but it's not working on my IIS server. It gives me an "404 Not Found Error" and the response on Firebug says "No input file specified".

Everything else on ajax works fine in my website, this is the only one giving me trouble. I'm thinking it's JSON problem because the other ajax requests I'm using are HTML responses. So I added the Mime Type 'application/json' to the IIS Server, but no luck. Also tried updating the doc_root in my php.ini, didn't work.

This is my code:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {


                "bJQueryUI": true,

                "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página",
                "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron clientes con esa descripcion",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado desde _MAX_ registros totales)",
                "sProcessing": "Procesando..",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                },


                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/clientes_particulares/get_client_data",
                "aoColumns": [
                    /* id */   {"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
                    /* Cedula */  null,
                    /* Pasaporte */ null,
                    /* Nombre */  null,
                    /* Apellido */    null,
                    /*Fecha de nac*/ null,
                    /*Venc Pasa*/ null,
                    /*Email*/ null,
                    /*preferencia_asiento*/ null,                   
                ],



            } );
```

By the way if I put that URL in the browser it doesn't work either, I have to add a "?" after the "index.php" in order to work and I see the output I'm expecting, but if I add this "?" in the sAjaxSource url it gives a '400 Bad Request' error. So again I'm almost certain it's json problem with the server, but ran out of ways to resolve it.

I'm using Codeigniter Framework and its datatables plugin.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: could be two things: either the url you're hitting on the server truly doesn't exist, or the url DOES exist, a script was properly executed, but happened to return a 404 response because whatever you asked for doesn't exist.

Comment: Let me correct something.. When I put the URL in the browser it doesn't work, it also gives me the 'No input file specified' response. I have to put a "?" after the index.php in order to work and I see the output I'm expecting.. But if I add the "?" in the ajaxSource url it gives me a '400 Bad Request' Error.. So what do I do?.. In localhost it works just as it is, without the question mark in the ajaxSource url, even though I have to add the "?" for the pages to work. @MarcB

Comment: If the server's complaining about a bad request, you can always include some bogus query string parameters, so it looks somewhat, legit, e.g. `example.com?foo=bar`.

Comment: Excuse me @MarcB I don't know what you mean. How can I apply this to my url? I'm using "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/clientes_particulares/get_client_data" to get all clients data from the database.. Btw I get this Bad Request with the question mark also in localhost, the one working in localhost is the url without the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the you restart IIS after adding Type 'application/json' to the IIS Server

```
cmd
iisrestart
```

Maybe the question mark is not being properly encoded in the datatable options, try the `&#63;` HTML number for "?" in your ajaxSource url instead and see if that works.

Comment: I did restart it. Still the same.

Comment: Let me correct something.. When I put the URL in the browser it doesn't work, it also gives me the 'No input file specified' response. I have to put a "?" after the index.php in order to work.. But if I add the "?" in the ajaxSource url it gives me a '400 Bad Request' Error.. So what do I do?.. In localhost it works just as it is, without the question mark in the ajaxSource url, even though I have to add the "?" for the pages to work.

Comment: I have updated my answer try &#63; instead of ? in the ajaxSource url instead

Comment: Hi I just tried this and still nothing.. It truncated the url as if the rest of the url to the right of "?" were parameters.. This is the output response in Firebug with your suggestion: "GET http://10.0.0.5/index.php?_=1379432203410 200 OK 81ms".. And the output with the normal question mark: "GET http://10.0.0.5/index.php?/clientes_particulares/get_client_data&_=1379432359244 400 Bad Request 22ms"

Comment: I think the way to go is without the question mark, since this the way it works in localhost. With the question mark it doesn't on neither, even though it gives me the output when I put the url in the browser (In both).